# The file that's calling props.children is not rendering the content in the parent

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router-dom

Default.HOC.js

```
import React from "react";
import { Route, Routes } from "react-router-dom";
import DefaultLayout from "../layouts/Default.layout";

const DefaultHOC = ({ component: Component, ...rest }) => {
  // component
  // props -> path exact
  return (
    <Routes>
      <Route
        {...rest}
        component = {(props) => {
          <DefaultLayout>
            <Component {...props} />
          </DefaultLayout>
        }}
      />
    </Routes>
  );
};

export default DefaultHOC;
```

temp.js

```
import React from "react";

function Temp() {
  return <h1>This is a temp component</h1>
}

export default Temp;
```

Default.layout.js

```
import React from "react";

const DefaultLayout = (props) => {
  return (
    <div style={{ padding: '10px' }}>
      <h1>Default Layout Page</h1>
      {props.children}
    </div>
  );
};

export default DefaultLayout;
```

App.js

```
import { Route, Routes } from "react-router-dom";

// HOC
import DefaultHOC from "./HOC/Default.HOC";

// Component
import Temp from "./components/temp";

function App() {
  return (
    <>
      <DefaultHOC path="/" exact element={<Temp />} />
    </>
  );
}

export default App;
```

The video lecture I'm following has used the older version, the problem is that when I'm calling `children`, only the `Temp` is being rendered, i.e, the screen only shows:

"This is a temp component"

whereas it should show the result as:

"Default Layout Page
This is a temp component"

I've tried replacing `component` with `element`, it shows the same result. Also, when I remove the destructured props and all, it only shows "Default layout page".

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!  Relevant code and error messages need to be included in your question *as text*, [not as pictures of text](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/328193).  Just linking to screen shots makes it more difficult for people to help you.  To learn more about this community and how we can help you, please start with the [tour] and read [ask] and its linked resources.

Comment: @David thank you so much for pointing it out, I've edited the question, please have a look at it. Thanks again in advance !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Issues

1. `DefaultHOC` is misnamed, it's not a Higher Order Component, e.g. a function component that returns a function component, it's just a regular React function component.
2. `DefaultHOC` needs to render the `Route` correctly, e.g. passing the correct props. There is no `component` prop, there exists only a single `element` prop that takes a `React.ReactNode`, e.g. JSX, as an argument.

The current code only renders the `<Temp />` component because it was passed to `DefaultHOC` on the `element` prop which was spread through to the `Route` component along with the `path` prop. The `component` prop is ignored.

```
<DefaultHOC path="/" exact element={<Temp />} />
```

```
const DefaultHOC = ({ component: Component, ...rest }) => {
  return (
    <Routes>
      <Route
        {...rest} // <-- path and element pass through here
        component={(props) => { // <-- extraneous ignored prop
          <DefaultLayout>
            <Component {...props} />
          </DefaultLayout>;
        }}
      />
    </Routes>
  );
};
```

## Solution

Refactor the `DefaultHOC` to render `DefaultLayout` and passed `component` prop on the `Route` component's `element` prop. I suggest also renaming the component since it's not a HOC.

Example:

```
const DefaultComponent = ({ component, ...props }) => {
  return (
    <Routes>
      <Route {...props} element={<DefaultLayout>{component}</DefaultLayout>} />
    </Routes>
  );
};
```

```
<DefaultComponent path="/" component={<Temp />} />
```

[image: Edit the-file-thats-calling-props-children-its-not-rendering-the-content-in-the-p]

[image]

### Suggested Solution

The above appears to be a very unconventional method is sharing UI via a layout. The idiomatic way to render certain components into certain UIs in `react-router@6` is to use [Layout Routes](https://reactrouter.com/en/main/start/concepts#layout-routes). Layout routes render "common UI" and possibly house "common state/logic" and render an [`Outlet`](https://reactrouter.com/en/main/start/concepts#outlets) for nested routes to render their content into.

Example:

```
import { Outlet } from "react-router-dom";

const DefaultLayout = () => {
  return (
    <div style={{ padding: "10px" }}>
      <h1> Default Layout Page </h1>
      <Outlet />
    </div>
  );
};
```

App.js

```
import { Route, Routes } from "react-router-dom";

...

export default function App() {
  return (
    <Routes>
      <Route element={<DefaultLayout />}>
        <Route path="/" element={<Temp />} />
      </Route>
    </Routes>
  );
}
```

[image: Edit the-file-thats-calling-props-children-its-not-rendering-the-content-in-the-p (forked)]

[image]